# Angular 2 authentication: logout stays in the user page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My app has 2 features: AppModule, and UserModule.

**UserModule** - for logged in users.

**AppModule** - login page.

I manage my auth in my `auth.service` and I also have guard as `auth.guard.service`.

When I call `auth.service.logOut()`, the user is logged out, but stays in the panel and route is not changing.
I also tried to add `this.router.navigate(['']);` but the user stays in the `/panel` route.

This is my logout method:

```
logout() {
      console.log("logging out..");
      this.auth.logout();
      this.userData = null;
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
```

I call this method inside my `PanelComponent`. The problem is that the user stays in the PanelComponent, and is not "kicked out" back to the login page, which is the `HomeComponent`.

app.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

user-panel.routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'panel',
        component: PanelComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            children: [
              { path: 'userHome', component: userHomeComponent },
              { path: '', component: PanelHomeComponent }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
```

When I refresh my page, I'm transfered back to the login. why it doesn't work without refreshing?

**Update: My home redirects me back to the panel, although the `isLoggedIn` variable has changed.**

my HomeComponent is redirecting me back to my panel although it shouldn't.

**HomeComponent:**

```
ngOnInit() {
      //If he is alredy logged, redirect him to the panel
      this.authService.login().subscribe(() => {
          this.loaded = true;
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
          console.log("Navigated back to worker panel!");
        this.router.navigate(['/worker-panel']);
      }
    });
```

in my logOut() method I set my `isLoggedIn` variable to `false`. Although, my console outputs `Navigated back to worker panel!`

Comment: Please add the router configuration.

Comment: Hey @GünterZöchbauer I added my panel module router. I placed the AuthGuard in both of my modules (features)

Comment: What route is active when you call `auth.service.logOut()`. What is the expected behavior? Please add the parent router configuration as well.

Comment: I call this method inside my `PanelComponent`. The problem is that the user stays in the PanelComponent, and is not "kicked out" back to the login page, which is the `HomeComponent`.

Comment: It looks like the route handling done in `HomeComponent` is routing you to the wrong component?

Comment: Yeah John you are right. I just noticed that my Home redirecting me back to the panel! I update my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your parent router as below and use `this.router.navigate(['home']);` in your logout function

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
])
```